# Distinct Subsequences DP explanation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

From [LeetCode](http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/distinct-subsequences/)

> Given a string S and a string T, count the number of distinct
>   subsequences of T in S.
>
> A subsequence of a string is a new string which is formed from the
>   original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters
>   without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters.
>   (ie, "ACE" is a subsequence of "ABCDE" while "AEC" is not).
>
> Here is an example: S = "rabbbit", T = "rabbit"
>
> Return 3.

I see a very good DP solution, however, I have hard time to understand it, anybody can explain how this dp works?

```
int numDistinct(string S, string T) {

    vector<int> f(T.size()+1);

    //set the last size to 1.
    f[T.size()]=1;

    for(int i=S.size()-1; i>=0; --i){
        for(int j=0; j<T.size(); ++j){
            f[j]+=(S[i]==T[j])*f[j+1];
            printf("%d\t", f[j] );
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return f[0];
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, try to solve the problem yourself to come up with a naive implementation:

Let's say that `S.length = m` and `T.length = n`. Let's write `S{i}` for the substring of `S` starting at `i`. For example, if `S = "abcde"`, `S{0} = "abcde"`, `S{4} = "e"`, and `S{5} = ""`. We use a similar definition for `T`.

Let `N[i][j]` be the distinct subsequences for `S{i}` and `T{j}`. We are interested in `N[0][0]` (because those are both full strings).

There are two easy cases: `N[i][n]` for any `i` and `N[m][j]` for `j<n`. How many subsequences are there for `""` in some string `S`? Exactly 1. How many for some `T` in `""`? Only 0.

Now, given some arbitrary `i` and `j`, we need to find a recursive formula. There are two cases.

If `S[i] != T[j]`, we know that `N[i][j] = N[i+1][j]` (I hope you can verify this for yourself, I aim to explain the cryptic algorithm above in detail, not this naive version).

If `S[i] = T[j]`, we have a choice. We can either 'match' these characters and go on with the next characters of both `S` and `T`, or we can ignore the match (as in the case that `S[i] != T[j]`). Since we have both choices, we need to add the counts there: `N[i][j] = N[i+1][j] + N[i+1][j+1]`.

---

In order to find `N[0][0]` using dynamic programming, we need to fill the `N` table. We first need to set the boundary of the table:

```
N[m][j] = 0, for 0 <= j < n
N[i][n] = 1, for 0 <= i <= m
```

Because of the dependencies in the recursive relation, we can fill the rest of the table looping `i` backwards and `j` forwards:

```
for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (S[i] == T[j]) {
            N[i][j] = N[i+1][j] + N[i+1][j+1];
        } else {
            N[i][j] = N[i+1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

---

We can now use the most important trick of the algorithm: we can use a 1-dimensional array `f`, with the invariant in the outer loop: `f = N[i+1];` This is possible because of the way the table is filled. If we apply this to my algorithm, this gives:

```
f[j] = 0, for 0 <= j < n
f[n] = 1

for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (S[i] == T[j]) {
            f[j] = f[j] + f[j+1];
        } else {
            f[j] = f[j];
        }
    }
}
```

---

We're almost at the algorithm you gave. First of all, we don't need to initialize `f[j] = 0`. Second, we don't need assignments of the type `f[j] = f[j]`.

Since this is `C++` code, we can rewrite the snippet

```
if (S[i] == T[j]) {
    f[j] += f[j+1];
}
```

to

```
f[j] += (S[i] == T[j]) * f[j+1];
```

and that's all. This yields the algorithm:

```
f[n] = 1

for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        f[j] += (S[i] == T[j]) * f[j+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: @S.H. you can think of it as `for(int i = 0; i <= m; i++) { N[i][n] = 1; }`. The big difference is that that way is *operational*: I provide an 'algorithm' how to set the values, whereas the way in the post is *declarative*: I only care about the values, not about how to achieve them. That's a more mathematical way of writing it.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how does the dp ensure distinct subsequences are only counted?

Comment: @frodo every subsequence is the result of one exact matching: some letters of `S` are matched with letters of `T` and some are not. The algorithm loops through the letters of `S` and adds up the outcomes when it matches that letter and when it doesn't match that letter with one from `T`. There is no third option, so there is no double counting. I hope this not making it even more confusing to you ;-)

Comment: great explanation! Not many algorithmic questions get answered on SO, let alone with such high quality. Kudos, and I hope to see more!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is wonderful, but something may be not correct.

I think we should iterate backwards over `i` and `j`. Then we change to array `N` to array `f`, we looping `j` forwards for not overlapping the result last got.

```
for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (S[i] == T[j]) {
            N[i][j] = N[i+1][j] + N[i+1][j+1];
        } else {
            N[i][j] = N[i+1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your final sentence. Could you please review what you have written and make sure it makes sense?

Comment: I was wrong The code written the two-dimensional array is also correct, both forwards and backwards for j is correct. but when we change two-dimensional array into one-dimensional array, we have to loop j forwards, we couldn't get the result in lastest looping(here is j+1), the result of last loop is stored in array f, and we have the "f[j] += (S[i] == T[j]) * f[j+1]", we loop j forwards so we make sure f[j+1] is not modfied when we calcute f[j].